# Continuity of the principal argument

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $$f(z)=\operatorname  \arg(z)$$ is said to be discontinuous at any point on the negative real axis because the limits through two different paths are different so the limit does not exist at any point on the negative real axis.

My question is what about the limit if this function at any point on (for example) the ray $$\operatorname  \arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ i.e
$\lim \limits_{z \to e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}\operatorname  \arg(z) $
 through the path $z=e^{i\theta}$ counter clockwise we get $\lim \limits_{z \to e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}
\operatorname  \arg(z) =\frac{\pi}{4}$ but clockwise we get
$\lim \limits_{z \to e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}\operatorname  \arg(z) =\frac{-7\pi}{4}$ does that imply the limit does not exist? I think since $\frac{-7\pi}{4}$
does not belong to the range of the principal argument then it does not make sense 
does my answer is correct? If not what is the correct interpretation of that ?

Comment: Your computation can make or not make sense depending on how you define $Arg$. One way to define it that leaves discontinuous (only) on the negative real axis is the following: Given $z$, write it as $re^{i\theta}$, with $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi)$, then define $Arg(z)=\theta$.

Comment: Observe that for this definition, in order to compute $Arg(e^{-7i\pi/4})$, you need to write $e^{-7i\pi/4}=e^{i\pi/4}$ and return $\pi/4$. There is not going to be a discontinuity at $e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: There are ugly ways to define $Arg$, that are probably never used except for this comment, such that it turns out to be discontinuous on the negative real axis and the ray $t+it$. For example, given $z$, write it as $re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in[60\pi-\pi,60\pi+\pi/4]\cup[-7\pi/4,-\pi)$, then return $Arg(z)=\theta$.

Comment: Principal, not principle.